# Create tar with directory and only specific files

Tags: linux, tar

I have this directory structure

```
/Foo
  A
  B
  C
  D
```

I'd like to create a foo.tar with this structure

```
/Foo
  A
  D
```

where files A-B-C-D **aren't related** so I need to manually specify which one add and no pattern can be specified.

If i `tar cfj A D` it just create the archive without the parent directory. How can i mantain the folder structure?

Comment: [man tar](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar): `--exclude` or `--exclude-from`. A pattern can be an absolute path.

Comment: @Seth I have no prior knowledge of the content of the directory. I have a file where are listed the files in the directory I have to add and just ignore the others. So I do know exactly which file I must include, but not the opposite

Comment: I don't really get your problem in that case. As you have shown you know how to include files. `tar` does preserver the directory if you include it. So it's just a matter of you actually providing that path. It does take it relative from your call location. So `cd /` and run `tar -cf output.tar foo/A foo/D`.